# android spinner dropdown custom

Tags: android, spinner

I use spinner to show something, this is my code :

```
ArrayAdapter<ClassName> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ClassName>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, nameList);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
```

with this code, when click on spinner, I can see text and checkbox.
after that, I try to custom spinner like this :

```
ArrayAdapter<ClassName> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ClassName>(getActivity(),
                        R.layout.list_spinner, tenfavList);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.list_spinner_dropdown);
```

this is list_spinner_dropdown.xml :

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAllCaps="true"
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:textColor="#0004ff"
android:textSize="@dimen/20sp"/>
```

when but with this code, when click on spinner, I just see text, and no checkbox.
how to fix it ?

Comment: Please write your question properly that what you want to do.. here nothing is clear that you want to set check box or spiner.. You use checked textview not spinner why?

Comment: I mean, when click on spinner, dropdown will show, and with text, has checkbox with this. but in here, I can't see checkbox

Comment: So use spinner and add custom layout in adapter which contains checkbox. If you want then i will provide you a sample link

Comment: yes, I mean like that, same thing when use adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice); sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I was rewrite my question, sorry you.

Comment: no problem its ok but next time write only that what you need and explain in conversation more..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, now i got your issue. Issue is only that you please add style in your CheckedTextView for checked or unchecked like :

Add File default_checkbox.xml inside res/drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_checked="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_checked" /> <!-- checked -->

<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_checked" /> <!-- pressed -->

<item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_default" /> <!-- default -->
```

In your Xml :

```
 <CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:checked="true"
        android:checkMark="@drawable/default_checkbox"
        android:text="sdfsdfsdfsdfdsfdsf"
        android:textColor="#0004ff"
        android:textSize="25dp"/>
```

Comment: Please check edited answer and let me know its useful or not

Comment: in default_checkbox.xml, I see "Element item must be declared" and this is error. why that?

Comment: add `selector` as root tag

Comment: are you added default_checkbox in drawable folder exactly and change your images of checkbox according to checked or unchecked

Comment: my pleasure, happy to help you :)